# lua <eof> expected near end

Tags: lua, computercraft

I'm trying to make a keycard door in minecraft using computercraft and it gives me an error at line 23 saying  expected

```lua
rs.setOutput("bottom", true)
while true do
  if disk.isPresent("top") then
    if fs.exists("disk/.cardauth/authkey") then
      f = fs.open("disk/.cardauth/authkey", "r")
      p = f.readAll()
      if p == "UDoFk6ErYM" then
        disk.eject("top")
        rs.setOutput("bottom", false)
        sleep(4)
        rs.setOutput("bottom", true)
      elseif p == "QmwZNWQsxFug6SMOYQnh" then
        disk.eject("top")
        break end
      else
        disk.eject("top")
      end
    else
      disk.eject("top")
    end
  end
  sleep(0.1)
end
```

Comment: You `disk.eject("top")` in every branch of your logic. You can safely put it once at the end of the `disk.isPresent("top")` body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an extra `end` after the `break` at line 14. It closes the conditional block prematurely. You are getting this error message because the `end` at the bottom of the file has nothing to close.